# Bootstrap 5.0.2 toggles are not working i am following freecodecamp tutorial to build a website using sass bootstrap using git bash

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass, toggle, git-bash

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJKCj8uAHz8&t=1993s) to build a website.

I have installed node.js version 13.14.0. I've also tried installing the latest version and 14.12, however I could not so I m using v13.14.0

I have the following dependencies in the `package.json` file;

```json
{
  "name": "amd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "personal sass",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass":"sass --watch scss:assets/css"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Bootstrap",
    "bootstrap-v5",
    "sass"
  ],
  "author": "Ajay Daniel Martin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.35.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1"
  }
}
```

and the `styles.scss` file that is linked to the html has the following code:

```
@use 'custom';
```

I have created a `_custom.scss` file to change the bootstrap accordion and colors properties/variables after the changes I have added this;

```
@import"../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

now for the code. I copied the nav and accordion from bootstrap exactly as per the tutorial but my Toggle is not working both in navbar and accordion.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is anything else working, such as, did you get the folder levels correct?

Comment: yes the bootstrap theme, cards are all working but the toggle is not working here is a photo of the results  https://photos.app.goo.gl/r32quGtv3Fqw9ccp8